# Sort Olap cube by totals

Tags: excel, ssas, olap-cube

[image: Olap Pivot]

I have an Olap pivot. I tried sorting by smallest to largest of 2014 Total. It works fine for the first measure values (Gross Written Premium GWP). But if I try to sort the next one (Gross Earned Premium GEP), the sorting for GWP revert to the default sort (so the numbers loses the sorting. GEP becomes sorted everything else becomes unsorted. If I sort Outward R_I Premium Expense then I lose the sort from GWP and GEP.

In summary, I can only sort one group at a time, and everything else becomes unsorted. Is there a way to sort all groups by 2014 Total?

[image]

So to further illustrate, this is how it looks like if I sort the second measure "Gross Earned Premium". As you can see, GWP is now unsorted itself automatically. It's like, you can't sort GWP, GEP etc all at the same time. Only one at a time.

[image]

This is what I'm trying to achieve. Ok. As you can see they are all sorted by 2014 Total. So please it is the same. It is not sort by a different column. It is sort by total. Total and total only. one and the same, thanks.

[image]

So just to satisfy Aron, Life is now all joined together by swapping the order of the column. But this is not really how I want to view the data.

Comment: You mean you want to do a multi level sort. Sort by x, then by y.

Comment: I've added an extra explanation. And to clarify, I am sorting by only one thing. That is the total. And again this is an OLAP pivot, not a plain table.

Comment: umm because the first column is value names? they are the Sigmas (sums) then sliced by reporting class? So in cubes, first column is the first grouping, so naturally life will be split, because they are the second column? This is a pivot table where you can slice and dice.

Comment: Hence you want to sort by Values name THEN by 2014 Totals.

Comment: nevermind man, when you sort by values, obviously the associated name goes with it.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of sorting the 2014 Total column, sort the other text columns (the values you placed on rows in your pivot table) by 2014 total ascending.

1. Click on the drop-down in the row label cell for Values.
2. Choose More Sort Options...
3. Choose Ascending (A to Z) by and then select 2014 Total in the drop-down box.
4. Click OK.

Now do the same for the Reporting Class Minor field.

5. Click on the drop-down in the row label cell for Reporting Class Minor.
6. Choose More Sort Options...
7. Choose Ascending (A to Z) by and then select 2014 Total in the drop-down box.
8. Click OK.